# How to remove duplicate numbers from text file using pyspark python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to remove duplicate numbers from a text file using pyspark python, but the operation applies only to row.
e.g my text file is:

```
3  
66  
4  
9  
3  
23
```

Below is the code that i tried:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from collections import OrderedDict
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
data = sc.textfile('file.txt')
new_data = data.map(lambda x: list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(x)))
new_data.collect()
```

I get the output as:
[['3'], ['6'], ['4'], ['9'], ['3'],['2','3'] ]

But I want:
[3, 66, 4, 9, 23]

Comment: Could you please explain? Sorry, I'm new to this.. Do you mean new_data.collect()  ? The above output is using new_data.collect()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mapping a dict function over all entries, which will return a RDD with entries that contain collections.

To simply get unique rows of a dataframe, use `distinct()`

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder\
       .master("local")\
       .appName("Unique Example")\
       .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.text("file.txt")
df.distinct().show()
```

Note that this uses SparkSQL DataFrame API, which is the preferred mode of operation for most actions, compared to your code which uses RDDs, which also have a [`distinct`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.distinct.html#pyspark.RDD.distinct) function

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed explanation. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume,  you are reading a text file with a single columnar data having only numbers as you have shown. Here are few possible solutions.

1.Removing duplicates

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.text("file.txt").drop_duplicates()
df.show()
```

2.If you would like to target specific columnar position of the text file, create a new column for that position and apply the same process.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = df.withColumn("col1", col('value').substr(starting_position, length))
df.select("col1").drop_duplicates().show()
```